# AndroidAnnotations in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

Is it possible to make

```
@Receiver(action ={MY_ACTION], local = true)
protected void MyMethod{
myMethod()
}
```

into Fragment ?
It works only in Activity...

Android studio get only this information : `Annotations are not allowed here`

Did I forget about what?

Answer (score 1):

You probably already have this right but just in case, first confirm you are using AndroidAnnotations version 3.1 or later, Here is an [example gradle file from the github project](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/blob/develop/examples/gradle/build.gradle) using the latest stable build (4.4.0):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // replace with the current version of the Android plugin
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"

def AAVersion = "4.4.0" // change this to your desired version, for example the latest stable: 4.4.0
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26

        // If you have different applicationIds for buildTypes or productFlavors uncomment this block.
        //javaCompileOptions {
        //    annotationProcessorOptions {
        //        arguments = ['resourcePackageName': "org.androidannotations.sample"]
        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

Then apply `@EFragment` and tidy up your `@Receiver` annnotation in your fragment class,

```
@EFragment
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  @Receiver(actions = "MY_ACTION", local = true)
  protected void myMethod() {
    // Will be called when an MY_ACTION intent is sent.
  }

}
```

For more information/docs, and a great `@EFragment`example :
https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-Fragments

hope this helps!